# c: break out of switch statement and for loop at once

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, switch-statement

I have a `switch` statement, inside `for` loop, which itself is inside `while` loop:

```
while ((size = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    switch (line[i]) {

    case '#':
           # if i==0 jump out of for loop
           if (i==0) {
```

how do I jump out of the case statement and the for loop?
When I use break, that only jumps out of switch.

Do I have to set some variable before using break inside the case statement, and then modify my for loop to check 2 conditions?

```
for (i = 0; c > 0 && i < size; i++) {

    switch (line[i]) {

    case '#':
           # if i==0 jump out of for loop
           if (i==0) {
             c=0;
              break;
            }
```

or is switch statement a bad construct for my scenario?

Is there some better, elegant way to do it?

## EDIT:

**important**: I don't want to jump out of the while loop.

Comment: You can use `goto` but it is a bit of a blunt instrument. As long as you only jump downwards and outwards, never jump upwards or inwards, and never jump past other labels at the same level as the label you are jumping to, then it's not so bad.

Comment: @Support Ukraine - I need `size` later. But what about my second code snippet: `for (i = 0; c > 0 && i < size; i++)` ?

Comment: If you can't (or don't want to) use `goto`, then a boolean variable and `break` is your main realistic option.  Sometimes, it would make sense to place the loop and `switch` in a separate function, and you can then `return` to exit them both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to put the `for` loop in a function in which you `return` if the condition you mention is met.

```c
void parse(char *line, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        switch (line[i]) {
            case '#': if (i == 0) return; // break out of the for loop
            case '@': something; break;
            default: something_else;
        }
    }
}

void foo() {
    ssize_t size;
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    FILE* f = stdin;

    while ((size = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
        parse(line, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Will there be a noticeable overhead, when I call function on every line? If I have millions of lines?

Comment: @400theCat  You're welcome! If you turn on optimizations, I doubt you'll notice any significant loss of performance. I'd go for a function and use that _until_ performance becomes an actual issue. Functions also helps making the code readable by breaking large chunks of code down into smaller, easy to understand, parts that only does one thing (and hopefully does it well).

Answer (score 1):

I have a broken untested idea, you can make a bool variable and inside the for-loop use &&.

You can do something like

```
bool done = false;

for(int i = 0; i<size && !done; i++){
switch():    
    case '1':
        done = true
        break;
}
```

Comment: It would be a more idiomatic use of `bool` variables to use `!done` in place of `done == false`.  It reads better, too: "not done" is easier than "done is false".

Comment: god i messed up my first answer on stackoverflow so bad i had to edit it 4 times to make it actually working and 2 times to make it looking better. thank you everyone in the comments though

Comment: @SupportUkraine — pointers are not `bool` variables, and there are other (mostly hysterical or historical) reasons why `!boolean` can be 'safer'.  Yes, it is somewhat opinion based; nevertheless, for true booleans (and not for pointers), the `!done` notation is, IMO, preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional variable which will stop the loop. It can be even nested loop and you can "break" more than one level.

```
    unsigned runlevel = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < IMAX && runlevel > 0; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < JMAX && runlevel > 1; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < KMAX && runlevel > 2; k++)
            {
                for(int l = 0; l < LMAX && runlevel > 3; l++)
                {
                    switch(getlevel())
                    {
                        case 0: 
                            runlevel = 0;
                            break;
                        case 1: 
                            runlevel = 2;
                            break;
                        case 2: 
                            runlevel = 3;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SupportUkraine read the question carefully before commenting **`important: I don't want to jump out of the while loop.`**

Comment: @0___________ - do I need additional variable, or can I set my index `i` to `IMAX` so that the for loop will not run another cycle?

Comment: @SupportUkraine *"Just don't do stuff like this"* LOL

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is just to move the if statement outside the for  loop and the switch statement as for example

```
while ((size = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {

    if ( size != 0 && line[0] != '#' ) {

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            switch (line[i]) {
            case /*...*/:
            //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to define a function that will parses the input when write

```
while ((size = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
    if ( size != 0 && line[0] != '#' ) parse_the_line( line, size ); 
}
```